# Ngrok doesn't run on linux arm

Tags: linux, arm, debian, ngrok

I'm trying to setup my own ngrok server. I have successfully tested this server when I connect with a Mac OS X, but with a Linux/ARMhf, I'm having problems.

To compile the ngrok from source, I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok.git ngrok
cd ngrok
make release-client
```

I also copied over `ngrokroot.crt` to the folder `./assets/client/tls/ngrokroot.crt` before running `make`. I created a simple config file:

```
server_addr: myserver.io:4443
trust_host_root_certs: false
log_level: info
log_format: json
log: /var/log/ngrok.log
```

Then I ran my ngrok with `./ngrok -subdomain linux -config=./ngrok.cfg 8080` where on port `8080`, I'm running a simple web app.

When I do this, on the server, I do get a new connection and it seems like it is established, but on the client/linux machine, nothing happens. It seems like the page command line just freezes (i.e. I do not get this:

```
Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       1.7/1.7
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://92832de0.myserver.io -> localhost:80
Forwarding                    https://92832de0.myserver.io -> localhost:80
```

I also tried to just download the Linux/Arm version directly from the Ngrok site, but running it returns the following error:

```
err="user: Current not implemented on linux/arm"
```

Note: I am using [this tutorial](https://www.svenbit.com/2014/09/run-ngrok-on-your-own-server/) to setup the server/client.

Comment: I ran into this; try diagnosing with `-log=stdout -log-level=debug`. In my case I found out there was no `/etc/resolv.conf`, so I copied in one myself and it got me a little further. Still trying to get things working, but I don't think the `err="user: Current not implemented on linux/arm"` error is a show-stopper.

Comment: I am getting this message but just as a warning WARN[07-07|10:44:48] failed to get home directory, using $HOME instead err="user: Current not implemented on linux/arm" $HOME=/root